# Is it possible ? move diff outside in integral

Tags: integration, differential

I have a question.
When we have following integral,

$$ \int _{\ }^{\ }a\ \cdot \ \frac{db}{dt}dx $$

Can we move differential to outside of integral like this ?
If possible could you tell me the rule name ?

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\int _{\ }^{\ }a\ \cdot \ b\ dx $$

a is some sort of constant or function. and b is vector(i,j,k)

Thanks you..

Comment: What variables does $a$ depend on?

Comment: Could think it is just some sort of constant which be multiply with b.

Comment: What are the integration limits? What variables do $a$ and $b$ depend on? (observe: if both as well as integration limits are independent of $t$, the identity is trivial).

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

Comment: Thanks Robert !

Answer (score 0):

Robert Lee commented the correct result. The rule is called the [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). So long as $b(x,t)$ is smooth in the region being integrated, then it is generally true.

Comment: I deeply Appreicate !